# flatlist is not re rendering in function style component when state changed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a full repo here https://snack.expo.io/8NOF1nuoW .

I'm trying to add some names and in on text change event I'm adding the object new data.

Since the array of object is a state variable. It is not reflecting on list.

If i add new data now then on next change of data the new data getting updated.

```
const [prodName, setProdName] = useState('');
var [data, setData] = useState(DATA);

const DATA = [
  {
    prodName: 'Screen Guard',
  },
];

onPress={() => {
       console.log(DATA);
       DATA.push({prodName: prodName});
       setData(DATA);
}}>


<FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.prodName}
          extraData={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.listView}>
              <Text style={styles.listViewText}>{item.prodName}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React don't know if you add data to an array, only if the reference of the array change. Flatlist is the same.

So to create a new reference to an array, you create a new array.

```js
const onPress={() => {
       setData([...data, {prodName: prodName}]);
}}>
```

Syntax:
`[...data]` create a new array by copying the `data` into a new created array `[]`, it's called spread operator. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @rock go with this solution, this is elegant :)

Comment: I thought the developers at Facebook are smarter than flat-list. But flat-list is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like below

```
onPress={() => {
       console.log(data);
       const updatedArray=[...data]
       updatedArray.push({prodName: prodName});
       setData(updatedArray);
}}>
```

You are not changing the state array, thats why its not getting reflected.
When you do this the change would be reflected as you set it to a new array.

Comment: I'm so glad to you. Kindly tell the reason why object cloning is done. Whats wrong with my code .

Comment: So react compares the array reference so it wont see a change so cloning is done